# Input File in Java

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I want insert sudoku answer with a txt file . My book instruct me to do as follows :

"It is cumbersome to enter 81 numbers from the console. When you test the program, you may store the input in a file, say `CheckSudokuSolution.txt` (see www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/CheckSudokuSolution.txt), and run the program using the following command:

```
java CheckSudokuSolution < CheckSudokuSolution.txt"
```

I saved `CheckSudokuSolution.txt` file in same directory as my java file and tried several times. But command promp shows following error :

```
"Error : The system can not find the file specified".

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckSudokuSolution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Read a Sudoku solution
        int[][] grid = readASolution();

        System.out.println(isValid(grid) ? "Valid solution" :
        "Invalid solution");
    }

    /** Read a Sudoku solution from the console */
    public static int[][] readASolution() {
        // Create a Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a Sudoku puzzle solution:");
        int[][] grid = new int[9][9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                grid[i][j] = input.nextInt();

        return grid;
    }

    /** Check whether a solution is valid */
    public static boolean isValid(int[][] grid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                if (grid[i][j] < 1 || 
                    grid[i][j] > 9 || 
                    !isValid(i, j, grid)
                )
                    return false;
                return true; // The solution is valid
    }

    /** Check whether grid[i][j] is valid in the grid */
    public static boolean isValid(int i, int j, int[][] grid) {
        // Check whether grid[i][j] is unique in i's row
        for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++)
            if (column != j && grid[i][column] == grid[i][j])
                return false;

    // Check whether grid[i][j] is unique in j's column
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
        if (row != i && grid[row][j] == grid[i][j])
            return false;

    // Check whether grid[i][j] is unique in the 3-by-3 box
    for (int row = (i / 3) * 3; row < (i / 3) * 3 + 3; row++)
        for (int col = (j / 3) * 3; col < (j / 3) * 3 + 3; col++)
            if (row != i && col != j && grid[row][col] == grid[i][j])
                return false;

    return true; // The current value at grid[i][j] is valid
    }
}
```

how can I compile this java program with CheckSudokuSolution.txt file using command line ?

Comment: "_Error : The system can not find the file specified_" is not a Java error.

Comment: The instructions you are reading are telling you how to run the code **after** you compile it. Your question about compiling it appears ti make no sense. The most likely issue you are having is a simple typing error in the name of the data file. Check very carefully (even better use copy and paste) to align the name the file is saved as and the name you are using to reference it in the command line instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Which commands are you typing?

I would think they should look something like follows:

`java CheckSudokuSolution < CheckSudokuSolution.txt`

This would be done after having compiled the code first, to create the **.class** files. Note that this is done in two different steps:

- Compile using the **javac** command.
- Run using the **java** command.

Only the second step will then use the text input file, and we would be more correct to say that we are running our program with CheckSudokuSolution.txt file as input; rather than compiling it.

In our example, the character < is used for passing the contents of a file as standard input to a program. This is called **redirection**, and there's a lot more information to find [online](http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/redirection.html) about it. The point here is that it is not java that has problem finding the file, but rather your shell, which would look in the directory you are currently in.

Therefore you should make sure that your directory contains both the .class file, as well as your .txt input data. If they are in separate folders, perhaps look into the *-cp* argument for the *java* command, which can be used to specify where your class files are.

Answer (score 0):

The file needs to be in the same directory that you are running your Java command from.

So if your classes are in a directory `classes`, you should run the following command:

`java -cp ./classes CheckSudokuSolution < CheckSudokuSolution.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I understand that you take the input from console and put it in `grid[][]`. However, I guess you want the file name as an input and read it from file.

```
try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("<absolute path of CheckSudokuSolution.txt>")));
} catch(FileNotFoundException fe) {
    fe.printStackTrace();
} finally {
}
```